# Filter in elasticsearch 2.2

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, spring-data-elasticsearch, nosql

How to filter documents in elasticsearch 2.2 before executing query. I refered this page, but still couldn't frame correct query.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/query-filter-context.html

```
{
"size" : 9999,
"query" : {
"bool" : {     
    "filter" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [ {
        "exists" : {
          "field" : "dvd"
        }
      } ]
    }
  },
  "should" : [{

    "bool" : {
      "must" : [ {
        "match" : {
          "rec" : {
            "query" : "CKS",
            "type" : "boolean"
          }
        }
      }, {
        "match" : {
          "date" : {
            "query" : "2016-03-09",
            "type" : "boolean"
          }
        }
      } ]
    }

  }]
}
  }
}
```

This is what i am trying to do.. I am having lot of Should clauses with each having 2 Must clause. Any one of should clause should match to retrieve the document. I have included only one should clause to make it simple. Query is working perfect. I want to apply filter over this. Filter documents before querying. But this is not working.

I am using Elasticsearch 2.2 ... Please let me know how to filter documents in this version of elasticsearch.

I think post filter is for different purpose.

Answer (score 1):

would suggest making a change to the filter part of the bool query. You can pass an array of queries to the filter item. It would than become:

`{
  "filter" : [
    {
      "exists": {
        "field" : "dvd"
      }
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: what if I want to apply two exists filter in OR condition. ie) if any one of field in exists filter exists, filter the doc. Its not necessary to have both the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your comment under Jettro's question:

You can use a bool query/filter inside the filter block of bool query like so:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "dvd"
              }
            },
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "album"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now documents with either the DVD field or the album field will be returned.